# Struts 2 Dispatcher initialization failed

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, configuration, struts2

I have a project to create a Struts 2 project and get user credentials but I'm failing to get basic text to output. All I get is a 404 saying the requested resources not available. I've tried re-creating the project and getting a fresh download of Struts 2.5.2 and tomcat 7.0.

**EmployeeAction.java**

```
package org.GTAC.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.GTAC.model.MessageStore;

public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MessageStore messageStore;

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        messageStore = new MessageStore() ;
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public MessageStore getMessageStore() {
        return messageStore;
    }

    public void setMessageStore(MessageStore messageStore) {
        this.messageStore = messageStore;
    }

}
```

**MessageStore.java**

```
package org.GTAC.model;

public class MessageStore {

    private String message;

    public MessageStore(){
        setMessage("Hello Struts User");
    }

    public String getMessage(){
         return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```xml
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" >
        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="hello"    class="org.GTAC.action.EmployeeAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-    8859-1">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p><a href="<s:url action='hello' />">Enter Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**success.jsp**

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-    8859-1">
    <title>Hello GTAC Employee</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2><s:property value="messageStore.message" /></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>GTAC Project</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter    -class>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**console**

```xml
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\u001\app\oracle\product\java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ant\bin;C:\u001\app\oracle\product\java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;.
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GTAC' did not find a matching property.
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1323 ms
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:25 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [172] milliseconds.
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
ERROR Dispatcher Dispatcher initialization failed
 Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Eclipse%20projects/GTAC/GTACProject/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/GTAC/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:897)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:478)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/Eclipse%20projects/GTAC/GTACProject/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/GTAC/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:238)
    ... 20 more
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Eclipse%20projects/GTAC/GTACProject/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/GTAC/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:491)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Eclipse%20projects/GTAC/GTACProject/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/GTAC/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:897)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:478)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/Eclipse%20projects/GTAC/GTACProject/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/GTAC/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:238)
    ... 20 more

Oct 24, 2016 4:10:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/GTAC] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 24, 2016 4:10:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12304 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar` 
(or whatever version you've included in your package). 
That's it.

You don't need it, and you should not have included it in the first place.

Comment: I did that and rebuilt the project, still getting the same error. I currently have all of the struts jars in my project minus struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.2.jar. I tried only adding the necessary jars but then tomcat throws an error. looks like im now getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: You can't get an error regarding the gxp plugin if you've removed it. You probably have *another* error, similar but related to another plugin. BTW the fact that you say "I've all of the struts jars in my project" is not a plus... You should have ONLY the necessary jars, not include every possible garbage trying to beat the record of the largest ear on the planet.